# Cannot install PyPdf 2 module

Tags: python, module, importerror, pypdf

Trying to install [PyPdf2](https://github.com/knowah/PyPDF2) module, I downloaded the zip and unzipped it, I executed `python setup.py build` and `python setup.py install`, but it seems that it has not been  installed , when I try to import it from a python script, it returns an `ImportError`:

```
import pyPdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pyPdf
```

Any help please.

I'm using python 2.7 under windows XP.

Comment: there's no errors during module installation, i tried to import it from python command line, i tried every possible name for the module (upper case), but without a result :(

Comment: yeah the module PDF2 directory is located in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages as you guessed , and i have installed modules before without problems

Comment: @Evert i've made an update , thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It appears the README file for [PyPDF2](https://github.com/knowah/PyPDF2) is incorrect. It suggests that

```
import pyPdf
```

should work, but it doesn't. This new module is imported as

```
import PyPDF2
```

(as suggested by the document structure on github, and after verifying myself).

For convenience, when e.g. working with older code, you can of course do

```
import PyPDF2 as pyPdf
```

Answer (score 0):

The PyPDF installer for Windows works well for me. (Win7-64)
[pypdf](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/)

Comment: You'd probably want to use PyPDF2 though. Could you perhaps check whether merging files work?

Comment: i have tried merging files, it works well, but i have had a bug when merging PDFs containing strange unicode charachters, the error described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781994/pypdf-merge-error , i have not found a real solution , so i used itextsharp for c#

Comment: @Dualinity: Merging files works like charm for me. I haven't tried with Unicode chars as the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out so far what the issue is. Need to check if further commands of `PyPDF2` works. The import `PyPDF2` looks for `PyPDF2` folder in the base location of python. In my case it is `C:\Python27\site-packages\PyPDF2`.

When virtualenv is activated, pip install `PyPDF2` does not create the above folder. Hence the error. I manually copied the PyPDF2 folder and `PyPDF2-1.26.0.dist-info` folder from my virtualenv environment into the base folder above and the error stopped. Just in case, I created new virtualenv environment and installed PyPDF2 with and without virtualenv activated and the error is gone.

My folder structure:

- C:\Python27\site-packages\PyPDF2
- C:\Python27\site-packages\PyPDF2-1.26.0.dist-info
- C:\Python27\venv2\Lib\site-packages\PyPDF2
- C:\Python27\venv2\Lib\site-packages\PyPDF2-1.26.0.dist-info

Python script is very simple to test the import:

```
#import sys
import PyPDF2

#print(sys.path)
print('hello')
```

I troubleshooted the above using the stackoverflow response to check syspath
[How does python find a module file if the import statement only contains the filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252040/how-does-python-find-a-module-file-if-the-import-statement-only-contains-the-fil)