# PyPdf Merge error

Tags: python, pypdf

When i merge several Pdf pages using PyPdf into one single page using `mergeTranslatedPage`, i got some unknown characters, these unknown squares are the characters not included in the last merged page, after some research i think that the method `_merge_ressources` not working very well , because the later page could overwrite the ressources of the older pages ,  i tried `page1.compressContentStreams()` after each merge but without a result.

in [this link](https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0BwyGQjPp56zjRzIzTG5oZGdRbUE/edit) you will see an example of the PDF that has been merged and the PDF result.

Any help please

Comment: Does this mean [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780668/cannot-install-pypdf-2-module) got resolved? Could you please indicate that there?

Comment: i'm having problem of install with the new version of Pypdf, but this problem is on the old version, i tried to install the newest version to solve it but i cannot now , so i gonna reinstall the old version to   hoping to repair this error

Comment: Can you put two of the pdf files that don't work right on the web somewhere?

Comment: i have made an update and included a link to the PDFs that do not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below solutions uses the [pdfjam](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam/) command to merge multiple pdf pages into a single pdf page. It's a very powerful command with many different options and good documentation. I tested the solution on the two files you've provided 4_P7.pdf and 4_P13.pdf. You can view the [merged.pdf](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/25840964/stackoverflow/merged.pdf) to verify that all characters are formatted correctly. The code below uses a 2x2 grid by default but you can change that by setting the grid argument when you call merge.

```
from subprocess import check_output

def merge(inputs, output, grid='2x2'):
    check_output(['pdfjam'] + inputs + ['--nup', grid, '--outfile', output])

merge(['4_P7.pdf', '4_P13.pdf'], 'merged.pdf')
```

There was a question in the comment below as to whether custom positions can be done as is the case in the questions example file. The same layout that was provided in the question is implemented below. It first constructs the top layout which is a 4x2 layout, then the bottom 2x6 layout, then finally merges these two layouts into [final.pdf](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/25840964/stackoverflow/final.pdf). The pdfs used in the below example can be [found here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/25840964/stackoverflow/layout.zip).

```
from subprocess import check_output

def merge(inputs, output, grid='2x2'):
    return check_output(['pdfjam'] + inputs + ['--nup', grid, '--outfile', output])

files = ['1.pdf', '2.pdf', '3.pdf', '4.pdf', '1.pdf', '2.pdf', '3.pdf', '4.pdf']
merge(files, 'top.pdf', '4x2')

files = ['1.pdf', '2.pdf', '3.pdf', '4.pdf', '5.pdf', '6.pdf', '1.pdf', '2.pdf',
    '3.pdf', '4.pdf', '5.pdf', '6.pdf']
merge(files, 'bottom.pdf', '2x6')

merge(['top.pdf', 'bottom.pdf'], 'final.pdf', '1x2')
```

Comment: Excellent :D , i would like to know if i can make custom positions for PDFs like in the PDF merged provided ?