# Where do I put the .so file from Boost.Python so I can import it as a module, and how do I use it with both Python 2 and 3

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, boost, boost-python

I have the following file in a folder called cpp_examples.

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <string>

const std::string hello() {
return std::string("hello, zoo");
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(zoo) {
// An established convention for using boost.python.
using namespace boost::python;
def("hello", hello);
}
```

And I ran the following command to compile.

```
sumith@rztl516-Lenovo-G575:~/cpp_examples$ g++ zoo.cpp -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lboost_python  -lpython2.7 -o zoo.so -shared -fPIC
```

It got compiled and gave me a zoo.so file. And when I tried to import and run the zoo.hello() within the same folder it worked but it is not importing outside the cpp_examples folder

```
sumith@rztl516-Lenovo-G575:~/cpp_examples$ python2
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import zoo
>>> zoo.hello()
'hello, zoo'
>>> exit()
```

The following is outside cpp_examples folder.

```
sumith@rztl516-Lenovo-G575:~$ python2
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import zoo
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named zoo
>>>
```

What might be the reason for not getting imported of that folder ?. And while compiling I checked for python3 it is not compiling at all where I changed -lpython2.7 to -lpython3.4 and -I/usr/include/python2.7 to I/usr/include/python3.4 in above command but it is giving me error while compiling

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.4
```

If I can get answers for these two questions it would be of a great help.
Thank you.

Comment: if `zoo.so` is in `~/cpp_examples/` then how would python know where `zoo` is when its run from `~/`?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252040/how-does-python-find-a-module-file-if-the-import-statement-only-contains-the-fil

Comment: @vu1p3n0x So where do I have to place `zoo.so` ?

Comment: @Sumith - Start up the Python2.7 interpreter, `import sys` and `print(sys.path)`. It should give you a list of the places you could put it and have it work. Your Python3 problem is more complex. You need a version of Boost.Python compiled specifically for Python3.

Comment: Thank you very much @Omnifarious. I placed `zoo.so` in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages and it works like charm in python2. Any suggestion on compiling in python3 ?

Comment: Yes, but it'll have to wait until tomorrow. 

Comment: hm, change it to `-lpython3.4m` and try that again. In general, you can always use `python3-4-config --ldflags` to get the required flags for linking.

Comment: Thank you @JimFasarakisHilliard I changed my command to `g++ zoo.cpp -I/usr/include/python3.4 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lboost_python-py34  -lpython3.4m -o zoo.so -shared -fPIC` it's working.

Comment: I would actually recommend setting the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable rather than stuffing a file into a directory that should be managed by your distribution's package manager.

Answer (score 2):

As @Omnifarious originally stated in a comment, you should look at the directories present in `sys.path` to find places where you can put your `.so` file. That's where Python will look by default when the `import` statement is found.

When you run Python in the directory containing the `.so`, it finds it easily since the first entry is `sys.path` is actually the current directory.

As for linking, you should generally provide the the flags that `pythonX.Y-config --ldflags` gives you, as described in the section [Compiling and Linking under Unix-like systems](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html#compiling-and-linking-under-unix-like-systems).

The example in the documentation also provides sample output for it using Python `3.4`:

```
$ /opt/bin/python3.4-config --ldflags
-L/opt/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -lpython3.4m -Xlinker -export-dynamic
```