# How to make Python update module install dir after moving folder?

Tags: python

I installed a Python module from GitHub. Here is an example of the commands I ran:

```
cd ~/modules/
git clone https://github.com/user/xyz
cd xyz
python setup.py develop
```

this installed the the module successfully in the current folder. Then from some other folder, I did:

```
cd ~/test
python -c 'import inspect; import xyz; print(inspect.getfile(xyz))'
```

which gave the following output:

```
/home/hakon/modules/xyz/xyz/__init__.py
```

Now, I decided I wanted to move the install folder. For example,

```
cd ~/modules/xyz
mv xyz xyz2
```

But now Python cannot find the module any longer. For example:

```
cd ~/test
python -c 'import inspect; import xyz; print(inspect.getfile(xyz))'
```

With output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xyz'
```

### Questions:

- Where does Python register the location of modules?
- How can I update the registry to the new location of the module?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252040/how-does-python-find-a-module-file-if-the-import-statement-only-contains-the-fil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#command-reference) for setup tools `develop` command:

> The develop command works by creating an `.egg-link` file (named for the
>   project) in the given staging area. If the staging area is Python’s
>   site-packages directory, it also updates an `easy-install.pth` file so
>   that the project is on `sys.path` by default for all programs run using
>   that Python installation.

So to answer the question to update the location after you have moved the project folder you can rerun the `develop` command (from the new folder):

```
python setup.py develop
```

Note: you could also unregister the project before you moved it:

```
python setup.py develop --unistall
```

but this is not necessary if you just want to update the location.