# Pandas Missing Directories?

Tags: python, pandas, strace

I am running a parallelized(using multiprocessing module) python script during data processing and am doing many operations on pandas dataframe. However, during the execution when I used strace on one of the process instance, I observe below:

```
stat("/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/operator",0x7ffcef5329b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/operator.pye",0x7ffcef5329b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)  
stat("/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas",{st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
```

I think the file operator.pye must belong to python pyconcrete module, but since I did not used pyconcerete to encrypt my python script, so my running script should not be looking for them.

**So my question is:**
Are the missing directory(s)/file(s) a pandas bug, or someone else have seen something like this before, and can suggest what could be the cause of it.

OR I can ignore these messages.

Really appreciate some comments!

Comment: My guess:
Inside the pandas source there are several `import operator` (operator being a stdlib module) statements. When the interpreter executes an import statement, I believe it checks all directories in the module loading path and loads the first matching file. So the trace is probably from python's import handling. If I am correct, you should probably see many similar traces with other file/directory names.

Comment: @[codepae](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3571/codeape) I see this message repeatedely for these 2 files : **operator** and **pandas** only that no such file exist, but all other are fine, for example:   `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1505388024, 898907379}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=118, ...}) = 0` but I was wondering weather it is an issue or I can ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You should ignore this.  It is not indicative of a problem unless it is happening thousands of times per process.

More on where Python searches for imports: [How does python find a module file if the import statement only contains the filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252040/how-does-python-find-a-module-file-if-the-import-statement-only-contains-the-fil)