# How to circumvent having to append path every time I want to use a package?

Tags: python-2.7, module, path, centos, package

so there is a package I am using that always has an import error.  The way I am solving this is by adding the line

> path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

before every time I import it.  How do I tell python to just check this location for packages automatically instead of manually appending the path every time?  This is using CentOS and python 2.7 if that's important.

Comment: I think it is anwered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15252040/1758363, change PYTHONPATH

Comment: Based on the answers there, I added:

`export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages"` to my ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile.  Still doesn't seem to work

Comment: Scratch that, it worked after restarting bash.