# Does import look in the current working directory before the path? or the path then the cwd?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, sys

Which of the following describes the behavior of `from [...] import [...]`?

- **cwd  first**: look in working directory first, then the path
- **path first**: look in the path, then the working directory

Consider the following scripts:

**Change Path**

```
sys.path.insert(0, 'E:\\demo_dir\\example_dir\\eg_dir\\test_dir\\')
from src import name
sys.path.pop(0)
```

**Change Cwd**

```
old_cwd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir('E:\\demo_dir\\example_dir\\eg_dir\\test_dir\\')
from src import name
os.chdir(old_cwd)
```

**Combined Script**

```
old_cwd = os.getcwd(); os.chdir('E:\\demo_dir\\example_dir\\eg_dir\\test_dir\\')
sys.path.insert(0, 'E:\\demo_dir\\example_dir\\eg_dir\\test_dir\\')

from src import name

os.chdir(old_cwd)
sys.path.pop(0)
```

Suppose there something named `src` in both sys.path and the cwd,
and that the `src` in the system path is not the same `src` in the cwd

Did we just import `src` from sys.path? or  `src` from the cwd?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does python find a module file if the import statement only contains the filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252040/how-does-python-find-a-module-file-if-the-import-statement-only-contains-the-fil)

Answer (score 1):

Only `sys.path` is used to search for files to load as modules; Python does not look at other directories outside of `sys.path`.¹ The current working directory will be searched only if `''` (the empty string) is in the path², so if there is an `src.py` in both the current working directory and another directory in the path, the one that will be loaded is whichever comes first in the path.

You will find that `''` appears at the front of `sys.path` automatically when you run the Python interpreter directly (including when you run `python -m modulename`). This is [standard Python behaviour](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path). However, if you run a script directly (e.g., typing just `myscript` where it starts with `#!/usr/bin/env python`) instead that script's directory (e.g., `/usr/bin` if your shell found and ran `/usr/bin/myscript`) will be added to the front of the path. (The script itself may of course add further items to the front of the path as it runs.)

---

¹ Actually, this is not entirely true; `import` queries finders in `sys.meta_path` first. Those can look anywhere they like and may not even use `sys.path`.
² You could also use `.`, `./.` or various similar ideas in the path, though getting tricky like that is just asking for trouble.

Comment: This is true, but you should add some details about when/why `''` is the first element of `sys.path` and when/why it is not.

Comment: @wim Good thought; I have done so. Feel free to edit if you can improve this.

Comment: Yes, that LGTM +1