# Do I need to place __init__.py in each directory in a directory tree leading to my class?

Tags: django, python-3.x, import, module

I'm building a Django project with Python 3.6.  I have created this directory structure ...

```
project
- manage.py
- scripts
  - run_commands.py
- commons
  - util
    - __init__.py
    - my_class.py
```

The contents of **init**.py are

```
from . import my_class
```

In another class, I attempt to import my MyClass like this

```
from commons.util import MyClass
```

but I'm getting this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'commons'
```

Am I creating my **init**.py properly?

Comment: From which module are you attempting to import `MyClass`?  Can you show the directory structure for that?

Comment: @ReinstateMonica, The directory structure has been updated.  I'm trying to use the import in the "run_commands.py" file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that `MyClass` is not located in `commons.util`, because you only imported the module named `my_class`, not the class itself.

Instead the file `commons/util/__init__.py` should contain the following import:

```
from .my_class import MyClass
```

I don't think this will solve your problem, because you would be getting a different error than the one shown, but you *will* get errors for this eventually.

### Update

First, I'd recommend reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15252107/10746224) for a good explanation for how imports work in python.

Basically, when you execute `from commons.util import MyClass`, the interpreter scans the contents of `sys.path` for a module named `commons`.
I assume you didn't set `sys.path` to include your project folder, hence the `ModuleNotFoundError`.

TLDR; you have 2 options:

- Manually set `sys.path` in `run_commands.py` to check your project folder (Don't do this!)
- Use Django's [`Command`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) class

To use Django's `Command` class, you will need to adjust your project folder similar to the following:

```
project
- manage.py
- commons
- management
  - commands
    run_commands.py     
  - util
    - __init__.py
    - my_class.py
```

Now in run_commands.py:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

from commons.util import MyClass

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(*args, **options):
        print("handling", MyClass)
```

You can execute the new command with the following:

```
python3 manage.py run_commands
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I first ran "source venv/bin/activate" to activate my virtual environment and then I ran "python scripts/run_commands.py myarg1 myarg2".  I did try editing the __init__.py file to what you suggested, but as you predicted, the same error occurred.

Answer (score 2):

It used to be the case that yes, you need to put an `__init__.py` in every directory that is going to be treated as a python module as without an `__init__.py` python wouldn't look inside that directory for importable code.

```
- project
  - __init__.py
  - commons
    - __init__.py
    - util
      - __init__.py
      - my_class.py
```

But as [Reinstate Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10746224/reinstate-monica) points out below this is [no longer true as of Python 3.3+](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/). So, depending on your version of Python you will need to make an informed decision.

Note, you might or might not need an `__init__.py` in the root `project` directory (if you need them at all), it depends if it has definitions that are part of the source tree. But you won't need it if it's just a container, like you see in the way most Django projects are organised, for example.

- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html
- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a need to put any content in the __init__.py file that is in the commons directory?

Comment: Nope, for just making modules importable they can all be empty.

Comment: Thanks.  Oddly, I'm still getting a "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'commons'" error with the empty file.  I even tried making the "__init__.py" file in the util directory empty.

Comment: With the empty `__init__.py` files you'll need to qualify the import in full like: `from commons.util.my_class import MyClass` but seeing as the error is firing from `commons` I suspect you have a misconfigured Django project regardless of the `__init__.py` situation. If you didn't use `startproject` you should start over with that. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not in a position to rebuild my project.  Do you think there are any adjustments I can make that would make this work or is starting over my only option?

Comment: Well (and meant with total respect), if you haven't got imports working then you probably haven't gotten very far with your project! I would highly recommend starting again using `startproject` if you are this unfamiliar with the basics. Using it will assist you in learning Django best practices from the beginning. However, if you truly can't begin again, then you should open another, separate question posting your `settings.py` and all the other details of your project configuration in full so whatever is wrong elsewhere can be debugged in full.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  I'm building a Python script within someone else's project so I think the fault is probably with me as opposed to the broader structure so I'll see what I can do.

Comment: This simply is not true as of python 3.3+.  [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3-3)

Comment: @ReinstateMonica thanks for that, i was unaware. i've updated the answer with credit to you and info to reflect the fact.