# Why built-in modules can be imported using 'import' command without being in the same directory?

Tags: python, import, module

For built-in modules such as datetime or random why can these modules be imported simply by doing so:

```
import random
print(random.randint(1,10))
```

While the random module is not in the same directory as my main file.

For modules in different directory shouldn't we use other methods such as the sys module to import them?

Comment: Because standard modules reside in the directory of the Python installation.

Comment: https://leemendelowitz.github.io/blog/how-does-python-find-packages.html

Comment: Would be pretty difficult if you had to import sys in order to import sys...

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does python find a module file if the import statement only contains the filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252040/how-does-python-find-a-module-file-if-the-import-statement-only-contains-the-fil)

Comment: Being in the same directory has nothing *directly* to do with with what is importable. What matters is the import path, i.e. the directories in `sys.path`, which will all be searched. When you execute Python, the working directory is *added to the import path*. So, it never really matters where a module is *with respect source code file you are running with the `python` command*. This is crucial to understand.

Comment: "For modules in different directory shouldn't we use other methods such as the sys module to import them?" No, not at all. This is **very important to understand**. A module being in the directory **does not matter**. It just *happens* that most people run a python file from the directory that contains it, so the working directory in that case that is added to `sys.path` automatically is that same directory. But this is **not how you are supposed to manage imports at all**.