# Importing a root-level file when a submodule file of the same name exists

Tags: python, python-import

I'm working on a Python project with a specific structure where I need to import a module from the project root directory, but a naming conflict is causing an unexpected module to be imported instead. The project layout is as follows:

```
project_root
 ├── foo
 │    ├── init.py 
 │    ├── main.py 
 │    └── constants.py
 ├── utils
 │    └── util.py
 └── constants.py
```

In `util.py`, located in the utils directory, I aim to import `constants.py from the project's root`. However, executing `foo/main.py` leads Python to resolve the import statement to `foo/constants.py`, not the `constants.py at the root level` as intended.

Attempting to import util.py from the foo/main.py and import constants.py from the project root in utils/util.py:

```py
# utils/util.py

from constants import SOME_CONSTANT

...
```

`SOME_CONSTANT` being imported from `foo/constants.py` rather than the `root-level constants.py`, due to how Python's module resolution works when the script is executed from within the foo directory.

I resolved this by relocating foo/constants.py's contents and removing the file. However, I'm seeking ways to retain foo/constants.py and correctly import the root constants.py without altering sys.path. Are there best practices or Python features that could help in this scenario? Or maybe my solution was the best one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does python find a module file if the import statement only contains the filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252040/how-does-python-find-a-module-file-if-the-import-statement-only-contains-the-fil) also [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Using pip install -e . might be a good solution among them. However, after following the answer and trying it out, I encountered the following error:
```
          raise ValueError("No file/folder found for module {}".format(name))
      ValueError: No file/folder found for module myproject
```
Why might this issue occur? Do I need to wrap all my code in a Python package for it to work?