# Import error in pyPDF2 when it is correctly installed

Tags: python, python-2.7, pypdf

I am using python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. When I run this command:

```
sudo pip install pypdf2
```

The following message shows up:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): 
pypdf2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
```

This means that pypdf2 is already installed on my system but when I try to import pyPDF2, this message comes up:

```
>>> import pyPDF2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pyPDF2
```

Comment: [maybe solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12782958/2050745)

Comment: Already checked that. Doesn't work.

Comment: PyPDF2 is compatible with Python 3.4.

Comment: What if you try install with command: `sudo pip2 install pypdf2`

Comment: Can't we use it in python 2.7?

Comment: sudo pip2 install pypdf2
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pypdf2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capitalization counts.  Try `import PyPDF2` and see if that works.